# Why are my grid-cells not taking up their allocated fr unit?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

In my project, I've noticed sometimes the grid-cells' height-dimensions are not equal to one another even though I've specified grid-cell dimensions with equal `fr` units (e.g. `1fr`). I haven't been able to recreate this problem. But I do know it happens when I put the `font-size` very high in the descendants of `grid-container`.

What're some common instances that can cause grid-cell heights to not be the same even when cell rows have equal height specified (e.g. `grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr`)? Perhaps then I'll be able to see what is causing this to happen in my project.

---

**The below snippet is close to what I have in my project. Currently, I'm unable to recreate the problem**

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(orange, blue);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div>
    <div>1</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>2</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Look dear. I have a question for you. When you write grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr; How much height do you expect 1 row to have?

Comment: *Currently, I'm unable to recreate the problem* --> so until then, your question is irrelevant. Try to recreate the problem or it will simply get closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CASE 1:**

Coming to your statement **what causes row cells, when equal fr units are specified, to be of dissimilar height to one another e.g. grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr**: I would like to teach you that

```
grid-template-rows:1fr 1fr;
```

has nothing to do with **rows-cells**. This only determines our flexible `row-heights`. A `cell` or `row-cell` or `grid-item` in CSS-Grid is the box shaped, created by both these properties `grid-template-columns` and `grid-template-rows`.

> In Developer Window we have a cool feature where we can see these
> cells once we however on our DOM element with CSS-Grid property.

When we do `grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;`. We cannot tell at the beginning itself how much of height would one row have if we have not specified the height of the container. The height of each row would depend on the content placed in any one of the row.  The row height would stay the same for all the rows, even when we have content only in one row or two rows. I mean the space would be occupied.

```
For Columns we don't have such problem, as column is calculated with respect to window viewport width
```

That's what is happening with you in your project. [image: Grids-Explained]

This image explains it more.

The rows will all increase and decrease as per the height of any of the row.

In **CSS-Grids**, we however in most of the cases work with columns only and use `grid-auto-rows` property in most of the cases.

**CASE 2:** Suppose we set our height and width to our Grid Container explicitly.
.grid-container {
height: 400px;
width: 500px;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
gap: 1rem;
}

Even thought we might have set equal fraction values for `grid-template-rows`. Each row will takes the height as per their content inside. So rows will adjust their content accordingly. `Since fraction (1fr) is used for each row. All the content should fit within and nothing should hide. In this process, widths of rows changes irrespective of being set equal.`

[image: Flex-Rows]

Comment: The code-snippet, that I say is close to my project, specifies `height`. But more importantly, this doesn't answer my question. It's irrelevant whether I know the exact height of cells because my question is asking **what causes row cells, when equal `fr` units are specified, to be of dissimilar height to one another.**

Comment: have used case 2...update . The reason is the fr unit itself mate :) fraction means flexible row, and our content should all hold within ... Hope you understood. That's why I have CASE 1 also in my answer. grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; have no significance yet. It depends on the content being used.

Comment: Sorry about that @ImranRafiqRather. I appreciate the time you're taking to help people. I'll go forward making an emphasis to clarify my question rather than just downvote.  As for the question, this answer's been great. Is it fair for me to say I've deduced this rule: if a grid-item's (`width`/`height`) dimension's `auto` & the grid-item's text-content 'overflows' its cell (set by `grid-template-columns|rows` `fr` units), the cell's (`width`/`height`) dimension will increase so that there's no overflow. Also, all cells on a row's height dimensions are equal to the tallest cell on the row.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, all of your grid cells are doing what they're supposed to do. Since you have set the width and height of the `.grid-container` element, the boxes take up the available space. If you aren't able to recreate the problem, you likely have some custom height or width elements inside of the grid cells that are influencing some of the grid cell sizing.

If you want to see a good visual of what's going on, I'd recommend your browser's Dev Tools (aka. Inspect Element), as they tell you how the grid is spacing inner elements. Another thing you can do is put borders on the grid cells to see if they're equilateral.

[Chrome Dev Tools for CSS Grid](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css/grid)

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.grid-container div {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div style="height: 300px;">Grid Cell 1</div>
  <div style="height: 200px;">Grid Cell 2</div>
  <div style="height: 100px;">Grid Cell 3</div>
  <div style="height: 200px;">Grid Cell 4</div>
</div>
```

The code snippet shows that the `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr` and `grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr` but that is overridden by the individual heights and widths of each `div` element (although I didn't show the example of widths).

Comment: `If you aren't able to recreate the problem, you likely have some custom height or width elements inside of the grid cells that are influencing some of the grid cell sizing` - this is what I would like to know more about. Can you give me some examples or rules of this?

Comment: I've added a code snippet in my original response, hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. In my project, when you inspect the grid-container the dotted lines (that, I believe, are meant to reflect 'grid-cells') are different dimensions. Is this likely to be a different scenario to your code-snippet (in your example the dotted lines are all of equal dimension)? If so, can you think of any scenarios where grid-cells become different dimensions despite each cell having the same specified dimension e.g. `1fr`?

Comment: You're right, my snippets' grid cells do remain equilateral although they don't appear so. CSS Grid is meant to have constant width and height throughout all grid cells unless one specifies otherwise. [Here's a CSS Tricks forum I found explaining this.](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/two-column-grid-layout-with-varying-height-2/). I can't think of a scenario where this problem would occur. Sorry I couldn't be of more assistance.